# Basic Sudoku checker

Tags: python

I am creating a basic sudoku checker with the help of Python.
However, the result is always displayed as 'False'.
The code is as follows:

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],
        [2,4,1,3],
        [3,1,4,2],
        [4,3,2,1]]

def sudoku_check(list):
    n = len(list)
    digit = 1
    while digit <= n:
        row_count = 0
        col_count = 0
        v = 0
        while v < n:
            x = 0
            while x < n:
                print ("Check")
                if digit == list[v][x]:
                    row_count = row_count + 1
                if digit == list[x][v]:
                    col_count = col_count + 1
                x = x + 1
            v = v + 1
        if col_count != 1 or row_count != 1:
            return False
        digit = digit + 1
    return True

print (sudoku_check(list))
```

I am new to programming. Would appreciate your help on this.
Thanks

Comment: Don't override the built-in name `list` with a variable of your own.  Use a descriptive name like `game` or `board` or something that doesn't collide with the Python language.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, John. I changed the list's name. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040304/help-with-a-python-sudoku-verifier-with-loops?rq=1

Comment: Unless I am reading this wrong (I do not use python), `col_count` or `row_count` will never equal `1` at the same time with this list value.

Comment: hey @ShreyashKarnik, working on a solution here. Would you be open to restructuring your code, or do you want it to stay very similar?

Comment: @PeterDolan Thank you for that. Appreciate it. By restructuring, do you mean to change the complete code? Or the procedure inside it?

Comment: A little of both! I think you could make it much more readable/simpler with some changes, but I can try to leave it as similar as possible if you'd prefer :)

Comment: @PeterDolan Yes, if you could make it more simpler, that would be great! Change is the only thing which is uniform :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, have a solution for you/can explain your problem @ShreyashKarnik!

## The Problem:

The issue in code comes from the chunk below:

```
while digit <= n:
    row_count = 0
    col_count = 0
    v = 0
    while v < n:
        x = 0
        while x < n:
            print ("Check")
            if digit == sudo_board[v][x]:
                row_count = row_count + 1
            if digit == sudo_board[x][v]:
                col_count = col_count + 1
            x = x + 1
        v = v + 1
    if col_count != 1 or row_count != 1:
        return False
```

So what exactly is this code doing? It's going through every cell in your sudoku board and looking for a digit. For the sake of explanation, let's say it's looking for the digit `1`. It checks every cell in the entire board, and since `1` appears 4 times total, `col_count` and `row_count` will be `4` every time. You can verify this with a print statement if you'd like!

Since your false check is checking against the number `1`, it's going to fail every time. So let's start looking for a fix!

## Making Things Pythonic

`"Pythonic means code that doesn't just get the syntax right but that follows the conventions of the Python community"`. You say you're new to programming, so learning the proper style of how to write python is important. You have a couple of issues in the code above:

- Confusing variable names
- Using while loops instead of for loops
- Lack of code modularity

Let's start with the last comment, lack of modularity and fix the other things along the way. Determining if a Sudoku grid is valid is actually surprisingly complex -- it has three components.
 1. Do all of the rows have the right number of digits? 
 2. Do all of the columns have the right number of digits?
 3. Does the grid as a whole have the right number of digits?

3 is actually a factor of 1 and 2, which you figured out in your code -- nice! But it might make things easier to read if we broke the first and second bit of things into their own functions. How might those look? Let's do rows first. For our function, we'll check each row and confirm that it has the right number of digits.

Let's start with the row checker. All we have to do for that is the following:

```
def has_correct_number_rows(sudo_board):
    # the set we create below is an unordered grouping of the numbers
    # 1-4.
    correct_set = set(range(1, len(sudo_board)))
    for row in sudo_board:
        # this if statement checks if our row contains values 1-4
        if (correct_set != set(row)):
            return False
    return True
```

This will return True if the rows all contain the correct number of items, otherwise it will give false.

Next, the checking the correct number of columns. This is slightly more complicated, but still fairly simple:

```
def has_correct_number_cols(sudo_board):
    correct_set = set(range(1, len(sudo_board) + 1))
    for col_num in range(0, len(sudo_board)):
        # col_set creates a set of the elements in a given column
        col_set = set([row[col_num] for row in sudo_board])
        if (correct_set != set(row)):
            return False
    return True
```

Same return values here.

## Putting it all together

Now that you have these two functions, your final check is actually very easy. It's below:

```
def sudoku_check_peter(sudo_board):
    correct_rows = has_correct_number_rows(sudo_board)
    correct_cols = has_correct_number_cols(sudo_board)
    # This last line returns True if both are true, otherwise
    # False.
    return correct_rows and correct_cols
```

This ended up being quite wordy which I apologize for -- happy to answer follow up questions or explain anything more! hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work and time on this.
:D Highly appreciate your efforts.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!!

Comment: Surely, it did!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudoku_correct =[[8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7],
               [2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1],
               [4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8],
               [5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2],
               [1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9],
               [7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3],
               [6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4],
               [9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6],
               [3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,5]]

sudoku_incorrect =[[8,3,5,4,1,6,9,2,7],
                 [2,9,6,8,5,7,4,3,1],
                 [4,1,7,2,9,3,6,5,8],
                 [5,6,9,1,3,4,7,8,2],
                 [1,2,3,6,7,8,5,4,9],
                 [7,4,8,5,2,9,1,6,3],
                 [6,5,2,7,8,1,3,9,4],
                 [9,8,1,3,4,5,2,7,6],
                 [3,7,4,9,6,2,8,1,1]]

test=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def isvalid(s):
    for i in range(9):
        s1=[s[i][j] for j in range(9)]
        s1.sort()
        if test!=s1:
            return False
        s2=[s[j][i] for j in range(9)]
        s2.sort()
        if test!=s2:
            return False
        k=(i // 3)*3
        l=(i % 3)*3
        s3=[s[m][n] for m in range(k,k+3) for n in range(l,l+3)]
        s3.sort()
        if test!=s3:
            return False
    return True
```

this is a simple checker for a proposed sudoku solution. it checks that every line, row and block is filled with all 9 different digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to validate rows, columns and squares.  Build a list of each 9-cell blocks as sets and check tha they all have 9 items:

```
def validSudo(board):
    return all(len(s)==9 for s in map(set,board))       \
       and all(len(s)==9 for s in map(set,zip(*board))) \
       and all(len(set().union(*cb)) == 9
               for rb in zip(*[iter(board)]*3)
               for cb in zip(*[zip(*rb)]*3))
```